# Get App Pool Identity for IIS in Power Shell Script

Tags: powershell, iis

Trying to get Application Pool Identity in IIS for a specific name, for example : *Test*

Succeded in getting it via below code but dont want to loop through all the webapps, is there any easy of getting it by specifying the name?

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
Get-WebApplication

$webapps = Get-WebApplication
$list = @()
foreach ($webapp in get-childitem IIS:\AppPools\)
{
    $name = "IIS:\AppPools\" + $webapp.name
    $item = @{}
    if ($webapp.name -eq 'Test')
    {        
        $item = $webapp.processModel.identityType   
        break
    }
}


echo $webapp.processModel.identityType
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Needed this but none of the answers had complete code so I put something together.

```
Try {
    Import-Module WebAdministration -ErrorAction Stop
} Catch {
    Write-Error -Message "Unable to load required module."
}

$webapps = Get-ChildItem –Path IIS:\AppPools
$list = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
foreach ($webapp in $webapps) {
    $Pool = "IIS:\AppPools\" + $webapp.name
    $sid = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier (
        Get-Item $Pool | select -ExpandProperty applicationPoolSid
    )
    [void]$List.add([PSCustomObject]@{
        Name = $webapp.name
        Pool = $Pool
        ServiceAccount = $sid.Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount])
    })
}
$list
```

Output

```
Name              Pool                            ServiceAccount               
----              ----                            --------------               
.NET v4.5         IIS:\AppPools\.NET v4.5         IIS APPPOOL\.NET v4.5        
.NET v4.5 Classic IIS:\AppPools\.NET v4.5 Classic IIS APPPOOL\.NET v4.5 Classic
DefaultAppPool    IIS:\AppPools\DefaultAppPool    IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool   
WsusPool          IIS:\AppPools\WsusPool          IIS APPPOOL\WsusPool
```

Answer (score 33):

Not strictly what the OP wanted, but google led me here for querying all App Pool Identities. This is my version

```
Import-Module WebAdministration;Get-ChildItem -Path IIS:\AppPools\ | 
Select-Object name, state, managedRuntimeVersion, managedPipelineMode, @{e={$_.processModel.username};l="username"}, <#@{e={$_.processModel.password};l="password"}, #> @{e={$_.processModel.identityType};l="identityType"} |
format-table -AutoSize
```

Answer (score 6):

Just combine the path and retrieve the item. This will work:

```
$item = Get-Item (Join-Path 'IIS:\AppPools\' 'Test') | 
   select -ExpandProperty processModel | 
   select -expand identityType
```

Comment: Used below , but doesn't work:


$webapp = "Test"
$item = Get-Item (Join-Path 'IIS:\AppPools\$webapp') | 
   select -ExpandProperty processModel | 
   select -expand identityType

Comment: Yea, because you have to to use `Get-Item (Join-Path 'IIS:\AppPools' $webapp)` instead of `Get-Item (Join-Path 'IIS:\AppPools\$webapp')`...

Comment: Works like a charm!

Comment: @MartinlBarandl The code works fine if the Identity is NetworkService but in place of it if the Identity is a specific user , say for example : Deploy\ABC then instead of getting the identity as Deploy\ABC, I get output as SpecificUser. Please suggest.

Comment: In this case you have to retrieve the userName and password property of the processModel object.

Comment: Still facing issue with the script, it does gives the user name but when customer is 
using a load balanced environment and the name of the application pools on the webservers 
are not the same. Currently I am accepting the Server Name and Database Name from the user in the
script and then getting the apppoolname from one of the table and then checking the identity.

The script is not yet checking the SPN's or the 'Trusted for delegation' setting of the 
apppool identity.

Comment: Are you comming with a complete new requirement and complain about the script doesn't do that yet?

Comment: Sorry for framing it in a wrong way, yes this can be considered as a requirement change, instead of getting the Application Pool Name from the database, I thought of getting it dynamically from the server. With
Get-WebApplication we get below information
Name             Application pool   Protocols    Physical Path
In the Physical Path I get the webapp path, I know the webapp Name so I have decided to loop through all the Physical paths and then get the corresponding AppPool Name but I am facing difficulty in Querying or filtering the Get-WebApplication to check the value I want.

Comment: Here is the way:
`get-webapplication | select @{e={$_.PhysicalPath};l="PhysicalPath"}, @{e={$_.ApplicationPool};l="ApplicationPool"} | Where-Object { $_.PhysicalPath.Split('\')[-1] -eq "WebAppName"}`

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but this is what I ended up using, which I think suits everyone?

Assuming $Name contains the app pool's name:

```
$sid = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier (
    Get-Item IIS:\AppPools\$Name | select -ExpandProperty applicationPoolSid
)

$identity = $sid.Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount])

$identity.Value 

IIS APPPOOL\MyAppPool
```